# Localized Names for SYSTEM Account in Windows?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I'm trying to get localized names of the `SYSTEM` account, I tried to google for it, but only find resources for Administrator account

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13813.localized-names-for-administrator-account-in-windows.aspx

At least in French system, the account is `AUTORITE NT\Système`, but I can't find the document online

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think there are localized names? // Also, what is the goal? It’s better to refer to the account by SID.

Comment: @DanielB At least in french system: AUTORITE NT\Système